Disconnected Metric Space Which is Not Totally Disconnected
A metric space $M$ is totally disconnected if each point $p \in M$ has arbitrarily small clopen neighborhoods. That is, given $\epsilon > 0$ and $p \in M$, there exists a clopen set $U$ such that $p \in U \subset B_{\epsilon}(p)$.
Given this definition, how can we define a set which is disconnected but not totally disconnected?
I was thinking about $M = [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$, which is disconnected. I think if we take boundary points like $1 \in M$, then no clopen set $U$ covering such point can be found contained in a ball with $\epsilon < 1$.
Is this true? and if it is, is there any way to show it formally?

$U$ would be clopen in $[0,1]$ also, and there are no non-empty clopen sets in $[0,1]$ other than $[0,1]$.

Your example does work. For it to be totally disconnected every point has to have an arbitrarily small clopen neighborhood, it's not enough for there to be one. That being said, in your example no point has an arbitrarily small clopen neighborhood, since even for a point like $1$, neighborhoods look like $(x,1]$ for small radius, which is not closed

It is true. Take $M = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ throughout. Let $p\in M$. Suppose $\varepsilon \in (0, 1/2)$ and $U$ is an open set in $M$ such that $x\in U \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(p)$.
We consider two cases for $p$. First suppose $p\in [k + 1/2, k + 1]$ for some $k\in \{0,2\}$. Then $U \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(p) \subseteq (k, k+1]$. If $\inf U = k$ then $\inf U \in \overline{U} \setminus U$. Otherwise suppose $k < \inf U$. If we had $\inf U \in U$ then there would be some $\eta > 0$ such that $(\inf U - \eta , \inf U + \eta ) \subseteq U$. But then $\inf U - \eta / 2 \in U$ and $\inf U - \eta / 2 < \inf U$ which would lead to a contradiction. Hence we have $\inf U \in \overline{U} \setminus U$.
Similarly, suppose $p\in [k, k + 1/2]$ for some $k\in \{0,2\}$. Then $U \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(p) \subseteq [k, k+1)$. If $\sup U = k+1$ then $\sup U \in \overline{U} \setminus U$. Otherwise suppose $\sup U < k+1$. If we had $\sup U \in U$ then there would be some $\eta > 0$ such that $(\sup U - \eta , \sup U + \eta ) \subseteq U$. But then $\sup U + \eta / 2 \in U$ and $\sup U < \sup U + \eta / 2$ which would lead to a contradiction. Hence we have $\sup U \in \overline{U} \setminus U$.
In both cases we note $\overline{U} \setminus U$ is not empty and so $U$ is not closed. Consequently, the point $p$ does not satisfying the relevant condition in your definition of a totally disconnected metric space and so it follows that $M$ with the induced Euclidean metric is not totally disconnected. Note that this works for all $p\in M$.
